# Remove all function documentation matching a pattern from a file

Tags: sed, python

Let's say you have many functions with auto-generated documentation similar to:

```scala
/**
  * @author John Doe
  */
```

Is there a simple way to remove these 3 lines from every function documented this way in a file? What makes this tricky is that it requires looking at a bit of context, rather than simply processing an entire file line-by-line.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```bash
perl -0777 -i -pe 's{^/\*\*\n  \* @author.*\n  \*/\n}{}gm' the-file
```

You would need to adapt the regex if those comments could be found with varying levels of indentation or if they had any whitespace (including carriage returns from the Microsoft world) at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to python (rather than bash) made it easier to come up with at least one solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import re

from pathlib import Path

def remove_doc(filename: str):
    fpath = Path(filename)
    content = fpath.read_text()
    pattern = r"/\*\*\n\s+\* @author.*\n\s+\*/\n"
    updated_content = re.sub(pattern, r"", content)
    fpath.write_text(updated_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Remove auto-generated documentation.')
    parser.add_argument('fpath', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    remove_doc(args.fpath)
```

Comment: Unlikely to be a problem for the OP, but beware that `\s` also matches newline characters so that regexp could remove comments that span more than 3 lines (where there are blank lines around the `@author` one)